Unit systemd-timesyncd.service could not be found
It seems that the computer time is not correct from the following outputs
$ timedatectl
               Local time: Wed 2024-06-05 16:31:58 CEST
           Universal time: Wed 2024-06-05 14:31:58 UTC
                 RTC time: Wed 2024-06-05 14:30:48
                Time zone: Europe/Brussels (CEST, +0200)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: inactive
          RTC in local TZ: no

$ nc time.nist.gov 13

60466 24-06-05 12:41:21 50 0 0 739.5 UTC(NIST) *


So as you can see the first commands shows the compute time is 14:31:58 UTC but the second commands queries the right time from a server and that is 12:41:21 UTC.
I also noticed that services are not working, so I ran the following command to start the NTP service and run the synchronizer.
$ sudo timedatectl set-ntp true
$ timedatectl
               Local time: Wed 2024-06-05 16:34:41 CEST
           Universal time: Wed 2024-06-05 14:34:41 UTC
                 RTC time: Wed 2024-06-05 14:33:30
                Time zone: Europe/Brussels (CEST, +0200)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no
$ systemctl status systemd-timesyncd
Unit systemd-timesyncd.service could not be found.


So, how to force clock synchronization?
